# Want to view deleted answer and comment stream:

Tags: discussion

So I asked the question:
[Thought experiment: ultra-fast outward push inside a black hole](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/314626/thought-experiment-ultra-fast-outward-push-inside-a-black-hole)

And there was a conversation I was having with one of the answerers (it didn't resolve my question but I wanted to read it all as there seemed to be some good substance there).

But before I got a chance to see the response to my comment it was deleted. I googled around (and i admit I might be dumb) but I can't seem to find a way to see the deleted answer without a moderator's help as i'm below 10K rep.

What should I do? OR would one of the moderators be able to send an image of the answer + comment stream?

Answer (score 8):

Even with 10K you can't see deleted comments. There simply isn't such a facility. You *can* see non-deleted comments to deleted answers, however, which is a slightly different matter.

And the official response to complaints about the inconvenience of that can arise because of that is along the lines of *"Put anything important in a post or take it to chat; comments are transient and the only official use case is to suggest improvements to the post, anyway".*

Of course the moderators understand that in practice they are used a little more widely than that. Try pinging one of us in chat to ask if there was anything interesting posted in response.

---

In this particular case there are several classes of comments to consider.

- There are several deleted comments under the questions. These were deleted by the posters and I wouldn't feel comfortable making the contents public. Sorry.
- There are some non-deleted comments associated with an answer that was deleted by the poster. Some of these seem to be part of a conversation including you. They were posted between 07:00 and 08:00 UTC by the user who posted the (now self-deleted) answer. If these are the ones you're asking about consider pinging the user who posted the answer in chat to find out if he'd be willing to copy them for you.
- There are some deleted comments associate with that deleted answer. These don't seem to have anything to do with you.